# Using Google App Engine for Wordpress. Are .appengine domains still available?

Tags: wordpress, google-app-engine, blogs

I have deployed a wordpress site using Google's cloud platform.  Under Deployment Manager I can view the settings for my site.  The site address is currently a twelve digit ip address.  Does google still give out free website.appengine.com domains?  If so, how do I assign one to my site?  If not, are there other alternatives I can use?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I believe the url for your mysitename appengine site default version is:
https://mysitename.appspot.com/

The url for a specific version (e.g. 55) of your appengine site is:
https://55-dot-mysitename.appspot.com/

You can discover the specific url for each version of your appengine site by going to the appengine control panel, opening the versions page, and mouse over the version number.
https://console.cloud.google.com/appengine/versions?project=mysitename&moduleId=default

Comment: When I go to the app engine control panel it just shows a button that says:  "Read about versions."  Under Compute Engine I can see some information, but nowhere does it show any other site addresses that link to my site.  I tried going to the default url you showed, but it doesn't work.  I deployed my wordpress site using googles Cloud Launcher.  Does that have anything to do with it?